# after WebBrowserTask how to automatically go to application wp8 C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Hello I am using a `WebBrowserTask` to download a pdf file. After downloading the pdf file I want to automatically go back to my application. How do I do this? Here is my code:

```
Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.WebBrowserTask wbt = new Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.WebBrowserTask();

wbt.Uri = new Uri(PDFPath);
wbt.Show();
```

Comment: I think this is a little different than the proposed duplicate. In this case, Nishant is trying to regain control of the screen from the PDF handler he launched. I don't think its possible, but it might be a good idea to leave the question open in case someone knows how to fiddle with Z-orders in WP8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WebBrowserTask does not have an event to fire when the download is completed. So, rather than using it to download the pdf, I would use this:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.OpenReadCompleted += client_OpenReadCompleted;
client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://www.somesite.com/media/PDF/xyz.pdf"));
```

Then the completed event will fire upon completion:

```
async void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
        byte[] buffer = new byte[e.Result.Length];
        await e.Result.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        using (IsolatedStorageFile storageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = storageFile.OpenFile("MyDownloadedFile.pdf", FileMode.Create))
            {
                await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
        }

        App.RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                MessageBox.Show("The pdf has been downloaded!"
                                , "PDF Download Success", MessageBoxButton.OK)
            );
}
```

Also, I need to give credit to [Tutan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1517883/tutan-come-on) for his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712224/download-save-locally-and-display-pdf-from-a-link), I just adapted it a little bit.

Comment: Thankyou but i want to pdf file store in localstorage or if is possibly to file store in external storage please help

Comment: So, you want to be able to store the pdf in external storage?

Comment: yes actually when i am file download from url using WebBrowserTask file automatic save in localstorage . so you give me code isolated storage file this is working but i want to same code to save file in localstorage . sorry for my English , is weak

Comment: Please Help me ... for this situation

Comment: If you want to be able to store the pdf in removable storage, you will not be able to do this, MS does not allow this for security reasons.

Comment: But if you want to store a file in the local folder, then I could try and help you with that. But maybe you should ask a different question, that asks how to store data in the local folder?