# Dowload a pdf from a link with c#

Tags: c#, pdf, download, webclient

I have a windows service application that needs to download pdf files from different public web sites and save them locally to a folder on the server

I tried to use System.Net.WebClient to perform the download like this

```
 client = new WebClient();
 client.DownloadFile(new Uri(fileLink, UriKind.Absolute), destination);
```

destination is the full path and name to the folder where I need to save the file to. example: \server-name\downloads\file123.pdf

fileLink is the url to the pdf file

One of the links I am trying to save is:  https://www.wvmmis.com/WV%20Medicaid%20Provider%20SanctionedExclusion/WV%20Medicaid%20Exclusions%20-%20June%202016.pdf

The code works but the file that is saved is corrupted and cannot be opened by Acrobat reader or any pdf reader.

If you click the link above and do save as and save the page locally to a pdf, then you can open it fine. So the problem is not that the pdf is really corrupted, but WebClient is not saving it right.

Is there any configuration I can do to the WebClient that causes it to save the file correctly, or is there another way to do it that does save it right ?

Thank you

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712224/download-save-locally-and-display-pdf-from-a-link Hope it helps

Comment: Open the file in a hex editor. What *does* it look like? It is possible that the Web server doesn't like your User Agent, and is giving you some html page instead.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote something similar long time ago

```
try
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    string originalFileName = response.ResponseUri.AbsolutePath.Substring(response.ResponseUri.AbsolutePath.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    Stream streamWithFileBody = response.GetResponseStream();
    using (Stream output = File.OpenWrite(@"C:\MyPath\" + originalFileName))
    {
        streamWithFileBody.CopyTo(output);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Downloded : " + originalFileName);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unable to Download : " + ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I tried your code using WebRequest/WebResponse but I still cannot open the file. Still says it's corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

After trying all the examples that I found online without luck, I finally figured out a way to do this. I am posting my answer here in case someone else runs into the same problem.

I used selenium FireFoxDriver to navigate to the page that contains the link, then I find the link and click it. I created a profile in firefox to download the file type pdf directly instead of opening it.

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(myProfile);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(pageUrl);
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText(linkText)).Click();
```

You can also find the link by href or id too, but in my case I needed to find it by text.